# Can I have Dropbox sync files outside my Dropbox folder?

Tags: windows, dropbox

Can I have Dropbox sync files outside my Dropbox folder?

I'm using windows & I'm try to use Boxifier app but it's limit and don't help me

Answer (score 0):

No.  Dropbox's simple design means in only looks inside the Dropbox folder.  You would need to find a different syncing program to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Thinks. Do you know another app?

Comment: Bittorrent Sync will let you pick specific folders to sync that are on a local disk